# DSYEV and DSYEVD for sparse matrix diagonalisation

Tags: fortran, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, lapack

So i have come to a point where DSYEVD is becoming impractical, due to it's higher memory requirements - it will need at least 240GB ram to diagonalise my matrix, so i'm considering moving to the DSYEV routine, which requires less memory;

[DSYEVD](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dsyevd.f) requires (1 + 6N + 3N^2) Words while [DSYEV](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dsyev.f) requires just 3N + N^2.

The *smaller* matrix i have has dimension ~100,000 and the larger has dimension ~230,000. Obviously the second will have to be done using DSYEV, but the first i can do using either.

I had a quick look on google, but couldn't find any relevant benchmarks - the only ones available have N=10-1000, and are dense matrices. My matrices are 100K dimension and 90% sparse, and 230K dimension at 95% sparse.

**Does anyone know how long i can expect this to take?**

I have already taken the first 3000 eigen vectors and values from each using DSYEVD, but now i need to take all of them. When only taking 3K vectors, using an iterative scheme, it took ~1.6 days for the 100K matrix, and ~3 days for the 230K matrix. The jobs were run on an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4640 0 @ 2.40GHz with 256GB ram.

Comment: Your matrices being 90-95% sparse strongly suggest you should look into sparse matrix eigensolvers, particularly since memory is starting to be an issue; ARPACK ( http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/ ) is one such package.

Comment: @JonathanDursi I have already been using Sparse Solvers, that's what the previous routine i was using used. It was iterative though, so while using it to get the first few thousand vectors isn't too bad, using it to get all of them is a nightmare (afaik).

Several different diagonalisers are used based on different parameters.

Comment: Please also look at SLEPc, which is a modern alternative to ARPACK built upon the PETSc linear algebra and solver framework.